COMET ERROR: Unable to verify Comet API key at this time
#@title Select YOLOv5  logger {run: 'auto'}
logger = 'Comet' #@param \['Comet', 'ClearML', 'TensorBoard'\]

if logger == 'Comet':
%pip install -q comet_ml
import comet_ml; comet_ml.init()
elif logger == 'ClearML':
%pip install -q clearml
import clearml; clearml.browser_login()
elif logger == 'TensorBoard':
%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir runs/train

I refer this code from ultralyric YOLOV5 and after I run this code then show output as below
COMET WARNING: Failed to check backend version at URL: 'https://www.comet.com/clientlib/isAlive/ver'
COMET ERROR: Unable to verify Comet API key at this time
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.


"Unable to verify Comet API key at this time" -> have you tried waiting a bit and trying again later?

Yes, I try again many times but it's still the same.
